# How to check if dt.AsEnumerable is Null before copying it UIPATH

Tags: linq, if-statement, uipath, uipath-studio

I am using

```vb
dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(
    Function(row) Not dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(
        Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    ).Any(
        Function(x) x = row.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    )
).CopyToDataTable()
```

Which works perfectly until Both A and B columns match. This leads to situation when "CopyToDataTable()" has nothing to copy and provides error.

How can I add IF to check if the item I am trying to copy is empty. If its not empty I want it to Copy the datatable, if it is the query should move forward.

I am newbie to all this! So any help is appreciated.

Thank you on advance.

Lari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have understood the question properly, you have ran the query below which works fine except then the result is empty. This then fails as `.CopyToDataTable()` has nothing to copy.

```vb
dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(
    Function(row) Not dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(
        Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    ).Any(
        Function(x) x = row.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    )
).CopyToDataTable()
```

A solution would be to use a decision or if statement with the below code, this will return true if there is data in there, then you can use the above code to extract it, if it returns false, you can then handle this without an error getting thrown

```vb
dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(
    Function(row) Not dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(
        Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    ).Any(
        Function(x) x = row.Field(Of String)("Otsikko")
    )
).Any()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You are an angel!

Comment: Did this work for you? Has it resolved the problem you were facing? If so can you mark/accept as the answer please.